# CryptoSwift AES GCM reusibility

Tags: swift, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I was reading about the implementation of AES GCM with CryptoSwift and it states that GCM is not reusable and you have to create an instance for every encrypt decrypt session. Doesn't this beat the purpose of having an AES key for both side of encryption and decryption? Im sure there is a part that my knowledge is too little to understand, so if someone could explain this to me that would be great.
This is the link: [CryptoSwift GCM implementation](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20GCM%20instance%20is%20not%20intended%20to%20be%20reused.%20So%20you%20can%27t%20use%20the%20same%20GCM%20instance%20from%20encoding%20to%20also%20perform%20decoding.)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. You have to create a new *instance* of the type for every encrypted file. Once you finalize the cipher object it finishes the computation of the MAC and gives you an authentication tag.

Answer (score 4):

No, the AES key can be reused, you just need to re-create the instances, so you'll have to perform:

```
let gcm = GCM(iv: iv, mode: .combined)
let aes = try AES(key: key, blockMode: gcm, padding: .noPadding)
```

for both encryption *and* decryption (in separate functions, of course).

This is usually because the `iv` and inner state of these instances are changed during encryption / decryption. Otherwise the instances need to keep the IV and other parameters in memory so they can be reset to their initial state. Usually encrypt and decrypt functions are called in separate parts of the code anyway; to encrypt and then to immediately decrypt only makes sense during testing.

Ciphers are lightweight objects; it doesn't make much sense to reuse them - most of the complex stuff happens when processing the data. Instead we can just reuse the key.